# autocomplete attribute not working

Tags: html, google-chrome, autocomplete

I would like to enable browser's autofill option by using the autocomplete attribute.

According to https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#autofill

```
<input autocomplete="given-name">
<input autocomplete="family-name">
<input autocomplete="address-line1">
```

The given-name and family-name should autofill the first and last name (western culture). I can get this to work if I add another field on the form for the address line. However, the form on my website does not have an address field, only first and last name.

This works, but I cannot use:
https://jsfiddle.net/gt6m1bgj/5/

This does not work, and I need it to:
https://jsfiddle.net/em8p92sb/1/

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the extended variants are just not properly supported by clients right now.

Comment: Would it by any chance work if you street field is an hidden field ? Just a trick but hey worth trying

Answer (score 1):

Both your cases are working for me in Chrome 51 (OSX) And Safari 9.1.1

I had a quick look to see if I could find a [chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?can=1&q=component%3AUI%3EBrowser%3EAutofill&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&x=m&y=releaseblock&cells=ids) that had been resolved since your question, but quickly gave up on that :)

Another useful reference is: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/checkout-faster-with-autofill?hl=en

Answer (score -3):

Autocomplete attribute only works with on and off value, also it require name attribute in input.

```
<input autocomplete="on" name="name">
```

Comment: As stated in comments in another answer, there are many more allowed values. Here you can see the specification with all of them: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete

Answer (score -4):

The autocomplete attribut tag use just 2 values : On and Off and the default is on.
You dont need do to something !

Look : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Comment: As of the spec there are much more allowed values. Please do not refer to w3schools – they are known for several errors on their pages. But all that doesn't tell us anything about browser support…